# fix n+1 query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have diagrams: https://app.diagrams.net/#LVenjob
In my Rails app want to create favorite job feature:

Controller:

```
#favorite_jobs_controller.rb
class FavoriteJobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_action :load_job, only: %i[create destroy]

  def create
    #code
  end

  def destroy
    #code
  end

  private

  def load_job
    #load the job
  end
end
```

```
#jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :history, only: :show

  def index
    if job_params.present?
      search
    else
      @jobs = Job.sort_by_date(page: params[:page], per_page: Job::JOB_PER_PAGE)
    end
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render partial: 'shared/job_not_found' if @job.nil?
  end
end
```

Model

```
#job.rb
LATEST_JOBS_LIMIT = 5
  JOB_PER_PAGE = 20

  has_and_belongs_to_many :industries
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :apply_jobs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorite_jobs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :history_job, dependent: :destroy

  def self.sort_by_date(page: 1, per_page: 1)
    includes(:favorite_jobs, :cities, :cities_jobs, :company).order(created_at: :desc).page(page).per(per_page).references(:cities)
  end
```

```
#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :apply_jobs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorite_jobs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :history_jobs, dependent: :destroy


  def favorite?(job)
    favorite_jobs.exists?(job_id: job.id)
  end
end
```

```
#favorite_job.rb
class FavoriteJob < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in view:

```
#index.html.slim
#jobs index
.container
  .container
  - @jobs.each do |job|
       - if user_signed_in? && current_user.favorite?(job)
          = render 'shared/unfavorite', job_id: job.id
       - else
          = render 'shared/favorite', job_id: job.id
```

this renders the 'apply' button if the user has not favorited this job or is not logged in

rails console result

```
↳ app/views/jobs/index.html.slim:10
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/views/jobs/index.html.slim:20
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 244 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 107)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 240 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 237 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 234 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 233 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 229 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 228 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 227 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 224 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 220 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 212 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 210 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 208 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 207 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_unfavorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 116)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (1.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 206 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 201 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 200 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 199 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 197 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
  Rendered shared/_favorite.html.slim (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 108)
  FavoriteJob Exists? (1.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `favorite_jobs` WHERE `favorite_jobs`.`user_id` = 2 AND `favorite_jobs`.`job_id` = 195 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:30:in `favorite?'
.......
```

i tried includes(:favorite_jobs) and something but it doesn't work
Please guide me to fix n+1 queries in Job index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this method:

```
def favorite?(job)
  favorite_jobs.exists?(job_id: job.id)
end
```

Instead of checking each job individually, I would load all job ids into memory once and then just check if a given id is included in that list in all later calls:

```
def favorite?(job)
  @favorite_job_ids ||= Set.new(favorite_jobs.pluck(:job_id))
  @favorite_job_ids.include?(job.id)
end
```

Note that this only makes sense when the list of all favorite jobs is not too big. A couple of hundreds is probably still okay, thousands are certainly too big.

Depending on your app you might need to add `require 'set'` to your model.

Comment: I would use `if favorite_jobs.loaded?; ... else favorite_jobs.exists?(job_id: job.id) end` to adapt the behavior of the method to if its loaded.

Comment: you use this in view? can you explain about `if favorite_jobs.loaded?; ... else favorite_jobs.exists?(job_id: job.id) end` 
Thanks for your help

Comment: `favorite_job_ids` return a array ids of table favorite_jobs and not return `job_id`, when you use `@favorite_job_ids.include?(job.id)` it not true

Comment: @HàMai I updated my answer to address our comment regarding the use of `favorite_job_ids`.

Comment: it worked very well. But can you explain why to use `Set.new`? Thank you very much

Comment: A `Set` allows returning the `include?` in `O(1)` whereas a simple array would need to iterate over up to all elements in the array to return the result. Initializing the `Set` takes a bit of time upfront, but the performance will be much faster in all subsequent call to that method.

Comment: @max This solution isn't instantiating models. It only loads ids. But you are right this is certainly not the best solution when the list of favorite jobs is very big – as I already explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way of solving the problem is by selecting a subquery:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_jobs

  def self.with_favorite_status(user)
    select(
      "jobs.*",
      FavoriteJob.select(1)
                 .where(user_id: user.id)
                 .where(FavoriteJob.arel_table[:job_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
                 .arel
                 .exists
                 .as("favorited")
    )
  end

  def favorited?
    favorited
  end
end
```

This selects `favorited` along with the other columns from the table:

```
SELECT 
  jobs.*, 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM "favorite_jobs" WHERE "favorite_jobs"."user_id" = ? AND "favorite_jobs"."job_id" = "jobs"."id"
  ) AS favorited 
FROM "jobs"
```

You would then build your other scopes off this one:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :history, only: :show

  def index
    @jobs = if user_signed_in?
       Job.with_favorite_status(current_user)
    else
       Job.all
    end

    # ...
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    render partial: 'shared/job_not_found' if @job.nil?
  end
end
```

On Postgres you can optimize this further by using a lateral join instead of a subquery.

The main advantage of this approach is that it does not load all the rows associatied rows off the `favorite_jobs` table which will slow your app down or even crash it if jobs have a lot of favorites.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, DB is fired for each check within the loop. I would suggest something like:

```
#index.html.slim
#jobs index
.container
  .container
  - cu_job_ids = current_user.favorite_jobs.pluck(:job_id)
  - @jobs.each do |job|
       - if user_signed_in? && cu_job_ids.include?(job.id)
          = render 'shared/unfavorite', job_id: job.id
       - else
          = render 'shared/favorite', job_id: job.id
```